# Scikit learn - How to use SVM and Random Forest for text classification?

Tags: python, machine-learning, classification, scikit-learn

I have a set of `trainFeatures` and a set of `testFeatures` with positive, neutral and negative labels:

```
trainFeats = negFeats + posFeats + neutralFeats
testFeats  = negFeats + posFeats + neutralFeats
```

For example, one entry inside the `trainFeats` is

```
(['blue', 'yellow', 'green'], 'POSITIVE')
```

the same for the list of test features, so I specify the labels for each set. My question is how can I use the scikit implementation of Random Forest classifier and SVM to get the accuracy of this classifier altogether with precision and recall scores for each class? The problem is that I am currently using words as features, while from what I read these classifiers require numbers. Is there a way I can achieve my purpose without changing functionality? Many thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can look into this [scikit-learn tutorial](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/index.html) and especially [the section on learning and predicting](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/tutorial/basic/tutorial.html#learning-and-predicting) for how to create and use a classifier. The example uses SVM, however it is simple to use [RandomForestClassifier](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html) instead as all classifiers implement the `fit` and `predict` methods.

When working with text features you can use [CountVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.text.CountVectorizer) or [DictVectorizer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.feature_extraction.DictVectorizer.html#sklearn.feature_extraction.DictVectorizer). Take a look at [feature extraction](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html) and especially [section 4.1.3](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/feature_extraction.html#text-feature-extraction).

You can find an example for classifying text documents [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/text/document_classification_20newsgroups.html).

Then you can get the precision and recall of the classifier with the [classification report](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html).

Comment: Thanks for your reply! My problem is that I am currently using words as features, while from what I read I see that Random Forest and SVM require numbers. This is where I am totally stuck!

Comment: @Crista23 I see. That wasn't mentioned in the first version of the question. I updated the answer with more info.

Comment: Thanks for your response! It was very useful indeed! I am still facing one issue when I try to vectorize the testData: vec = DictVectorizer(sparse=False) testFeatures1 = vec.fit_transform(testFeatures) gives me a Memory Error. It works ok in the case of the train data since I have around 8000 instances, but on the test data there are 80000 and it displays a memory error. Is there anything I can do abut that? I really need to test on all test data. Thanks!

Comment: @Crista23 that seems like an entirely different question. Depending on your use case there might be different approaches. I suggest you post a new question with some more details so that others can contribute as well. Also, try searching [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/scikit-learn), there might be some similar questions already.

Comment: You can try to classify the test set in batches.

Comment: Crista23 - try using a Hashing vectorizer - it uses less memory.

Comment: The links are dead now, could you share the relevant links again?

Comment: @ivan_bilan thanks for pointing it out. The links are updated now